# PTR entry is setting my hostname. How do I stop it?

Tags: domain-name-system, redhat, hostname

I'm running RHEL 6.5. My machine is getting it's IP address from our DHCP server. I'm getting this strange behavior where the machine will apparently query the DNS server for a PTR entry for the IP it's assigned and set it's hostname to whatever is in DNS.

If I comment out the PTR entry, it will get localhost.localdomain as the hostname. If I have DHCP fixed-assign an IP address that has a different PTR entry, it'll pick up that entry's hostname as it's hostname. However, if I set /etc/sysconfig/networks to anything other than localhost.localdomain, it will pick use that value as it's hostname.

Is this supposed to be happening and is it possible to stop it so that it stays as localhost.localdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
However, if I set /etc/sysconfig/networks to anything other than localhost.localdomain, it will pick use that value as it's hostname.
```

... that's how it's supposed to work.  If you look in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions` you will see the following:

```
need_hostname ()
{
    CHECK_HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
    if [ "$CHECK_HOSTNAME" = "(none)" -o "$CHECK_HOSTNAME" = "localhost" -o \
        "$CHECK_HOSTNAME" = "localhost.localdomain" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

So yes, if you change it to anything other than localhost.localdomain it will work.  If you absolutely need it to remain *localhost.localdomain* for some odd reason, edit the function (and remember to do it again if/when the file gets updated via a package).